# Exception in Service NOW attachment API invocation-- Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected

Tags: multipartform-data, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient to send POST multipart request, using the below code

```
                String apiUrl = API_URL_DEV;
                String name = API_USER_DEV;
                String password = API_PASSWORD_DEV;
                String authString = name + ":" + password;
                String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authString.getBytes());
                apiUrl = "https://<servicenow host>/api/now/attachment/upload";

                try {
                    Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data");
                    Header header2 = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
                    Header header3 = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoding);

                List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
                headers.add(header);
                headers.add(header2);
                headers.add(header3);

                HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("xxxx", 8080, "http");

                CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                        .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
                        .setProxy(proxy)
                        .build();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
                String textFileName = "C:/Heena_Code/Test.xlsx";

                File file = new File(textFileName);
                MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
                StringBody stringBody1 = new StringBody("change_request", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                StringBody stringBody2 = new StringBody("a81c6a1ddb2948d04af824f4059619a9", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

                builder.addPart("table_name", stringBody1);
                builder.addPart("table_sys_id", stringBody2);
                builder.addPart("uploadFile", fileBody);
                HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

                post.setEntity(entity);

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = client.execute(post, responseHandler); -----> exception here
                System.out.println(responseBody);
```

Getting exception

Severe:   org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:263)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.close(ChunkedInputStream.java:312)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.streamClosed(ResponseEntityProxy.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:172)
    at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.close(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractResponseHandler.handleResponse(AbstractResponseHandler.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:52)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:140)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach and used a MultiPartUtility class to fire request through HTTPUrlConnection passing two form fields in text/plain format and the file in application/octetstream format and binary encoding